# spring boot and freemarker configure TemplateDirectiveModel and TemplateMethodModelEx

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I have a project built with Spring Boot + FreeMarker, and it worked fine until tonight, but I don't think I had changed anything; however it failed. Below is my FreeMarker configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class FreemarkerConfiguration extends FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.FreeMarkerWebConfiguration {

    /**
     * autowired all implementations of freemarker.template.TemplateDirectiveModel
     */
    @Autowired
    Map<String, TemplateDirectiveModel> directiveModelMap;
    /**
     * autowired all implementations of freemarker.template.TemplateMethodModelEx
     */
    @Autowired
    Map<String, TemplateMethodModelEx> methodModelExMap;


    private static final String CUSTOM_DIRECTIVE_SUFFIX = "Directive";

    private static final String CUSTOM_METHOD_SUFFIX = "Method";


    @Override
    public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {

        FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = super.freeMarkerConfigurer();

        Map<String, Object> sharedVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(directiveModelMap)) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, TemplateDirectiveModel> entry : directiveModelMap.entrySet()) {
                map.put(StringUtils.uncapitalize(entry.getKey()).replaceAll(CUSTOM_DIRECTIVE_SUFFIX, ""), entry.getValue());
            }
            sharedVariables.putAll(map);
        }

        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(this.methodModelExMap)) {
            Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, TemplateMethodModelEx> entry : this.methodModelExMap.entrySet()) {
                map.put(StringUtils.uncapitalize(entry.getKey()).replaceAll(CUSTOM_METHOD_SUFFIX, ""), entry.getValue());
            }
            sharedVariables.putAll(map);
        }

        BeansWrapper beansWrapper = new BeansWrapperBuilder(freemarker.template.Configuration.DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS).build();
        sharedVariables.put("enums", beansWrapper.getEnumModels());

        configurer.setFreemarkerVariables(sharedVariables);

        return configurer;
    }

}
```

Problem is that

```
 @Autowired
 Map<String, TemplateDirectiveModel> directiveModelMap;
 @Autowired
 Map<String, TemplateMethodModelEx> methodModelExMap;
```

I want to inject all implementations of TemplateDirectiveModel and TemplateMethodModelEx , but both `Map<String ,TemplateDirectiveModel/TemplateMethodModelEx>` got `null`. Of course, the implementations annotated with `@Compoment`. I don't know why, I compared the diffs but got no answers, why the `Maps` instantiated after

```
@Override
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer(){ .... }
```

Here's my `boot application`

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.hmxx.entity")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = {"com.hmxx.service"})
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(new Object[]{Application.class});

        app.setWebEnvironment(true);
        //app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);
        Map<String, TemplateDirectiveModel> directiveModelMap = ctx.getBeansOfType(TemplateDirectiveModel.class); 
        Map<String, TemplateMethodModelEx> methodModelExMap = ctx.getBeansOfType(TemplateMethodModelEx.class); 
    }

    @Autowired
    DataInitService dataInitService;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
//        dataInitService.initAdminUser();
    }
}
```

And obviously `Map<String, TemplateDirectiveModel>、Map<String, TemplateMethodModelEx> methodModelExMap` both not null.

I want to know why the injection got `null` and hope to resolve it.

Comment: Interesting ! Same code , different computer have different results ; On my pc for working , preoblems haven't appear . It's really weired ! And I have'nt found a solution so far .